# Can I mix dual and triple channel ram?

Tags: memory

My motherboard has 6 memory slots, when I first built it I used 3x2gb sticks of DDR3 memory - which was plenty at the time.

However, now that its time to upgrade, it is much cheaper to buy a second pair of 2x4gb memory sticks. Can I have 3x2gb and 2x4gb memory on my motherboard? Will this cause performance issues?

Comment: Your motherboard unlikely will even POST in the described config

Comment: What motherboard exactly?